# Is there a documentation of whats the best way to make an Microsoft Graph API Call in ASP.NET Core 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I‘m trying to learn ASP.NET Core MVC and I want to make an API call to Microsoft‘s Graph API.

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC project and implemented the identity platform. Now I want to get the signed in users information like `DisplayName`.

I searched the internet for a documentation to the Microsoft.Graph.Core NuGet package but even Microsoft's learn page is still on .NET 4.8 and with removing of the `Startup.cs` file and managing over the `Program.cs` file I'm kinda lost here.

I even asked the ChatGPT for help and this is what I got till now:

GraphService.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ClientMaster.Services.GraphService
{
    public class GraphService : IGraphService
    {
        private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _clientApplication;
        private readonly string[] _scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        public GraphService(IConfidentialClientApplication clientApplication)
        {
            _clientApplication = clientApplication;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUser()
        {
            var authResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }));

            var user = await graphClient.Users["me"].Request().GetAsync();
            return user;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetUserMail()
        {
            var authResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }));

            var user = await graphClient.Users["me"].Request().Select("mail").GetAsync();
            return user.Mail;
        }
    }
}
```

IGraphService.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClientMaster.Services.GraphService
{
    public interface IGraphService
    {
        Task<User> GetUser();
    }
}
```

and my `HomeController`:

```
using ClientMaster.Models;
using ClientMaster.Services.GraphService;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ClientMaster.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private GraphService _graphService;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, GraphService graphService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphService = graphService;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var user = await _graphService.GetUser();
            return View(user);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

ChatGPT also told me to "activate" the service in the Startup.cs file. I came up with this line to add it to the program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGraphService, GraphService>();
```

But when I do so, I can't start the web server

Comment: What do you mean "Can't start the web server"? What's stopping you?

Comment: When i try to start without debugging with https i get a small error window thats saying, that the webserver could not get started because it cant be reached

Comment: Did you try wrapping your startup process in a try/catch so you can log the startup error somewhere? Remember, you're the one at the computer, so it's your responsibility to debug the thing. We can't run the debugger for you or modify your code or even see anything beyond what you show us.

Comment: You mentioned `get the signed in users information like DisplayName`, so you need to integrate microsoft identity into your application. this will help you add authentication. Then you can use graph SDK to call graph api, no need to create a separate graph service by yourself.

Comment: By the way I noticed the scope you used in your service is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` which is not correct for your requirement.  This is used when there's no users signed in. But you do have users to sign in and check the information for the signed in user.

Comment: Any update on this case?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate AAD into your application so that you can let your users sign in, then show the signed in user's information, this needs you to do following steps. You can also use [the sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph#readme). You can follow the sample readme to obtain the value you required to set in `appsettings.json` file.

add `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in `Shared` folder for login:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
}
else
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

change `_layout.cshtml` to add the partial view.

[image]

appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "tenant_id",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id",
    "ClientId": "azure_ad_app_id",
    "ClientSecret": "azure_ad_app_client_secret",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
```

Program.cs, also need to add `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();`.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' '))
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Add `[Authorize]` for home controller and inject graph client for calling graph api,

```
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    return View();
}
```

Used nuget packages:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.25.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.25.10" />
  </ItemGroup>
```